# Asp.net MVC Dynamically set TextArea

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I'm working on an Asp.net MVC5 application.

I need to write some XML into a textarea, so it could be parsed by some JavaScript later in my project. As of now I have loaded the XML info into a ViewBag and was wondering how I could dynamically set a textarea with this information.

my controller (Index):

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("C:\\Tasks.xml");
        ViewBag.xml = doc.InnerXml();
```

Thanks, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to edit and save the XML after you show it in the `<textarea>` or do you need it just to be shown there?

Comment: Just need it to show there, I will using it as a load, so every time a user reloads (including first load) the info to be displayed will be read from the textarea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
-- html form

    @Html.TextArea("xml")
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />

-- html form
```

post action

```
[HttpPost]
public Actionresult SomeAction(string xml){...}
```

---

better solution (using strongly typed views)

**model**

```
public class XmlViewModel
{
    public string Xml { get; set; }
}
```

controller

```
public Actionresult SomeAction()
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load("C:\\Tasks.xml");
    var model = new XmlViewModel
    {
        Xml = doc.InnerXml();
    }

    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public Actionresult SomeAction(XmlViewModel model)
{
    ...       

    return View(model);
}
```

**view**

```
@model XmlViewModel 

-- html form

    @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Xml)
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />

-- html form
```

Comment: Thanks, ill try implementing the better approach using the Model.
one question, Why do I need the helper function in a form?

Comment: You dont need to use helpers, this is an optional, of course you can use pure html (<textarea>). You need to set the name and id attribute of textarea with the model property name. HtmlHelpers are have more elegant syntax. There is no difference.

Comment: I understand the use of helpers, I meant to say, why do i have to put the @Html.textareafor inside of a form? Also, how would I add an ID to this textarea?

Comment: You dont have to use helpers, if use @HtmlTextAreaFor(x=>x.Xml) then your textarea id will be "Xml", you can see it in your page source. you can set it manually, too. Read some article about html helpers...